# rust gpu_allocator bufferDeviceAddress must be enabbled

Tags: validation, memory, rust, gpu, vulkan

I am using ash and gpu_allocator to try to port some C++ code to rust.

I am running into a validation error that the C++ code never runs into:

```
"Validation Error: [ VUID-VkMemoryAllocateInfo-flags-03331 ] Object 0: handle = 0x56443b02d140, name = Logical device from NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xf972dfbf | If VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT is set, bufferDeviceAddress must be enabled. The Vulkan spec states: If VkMemoryAllocateFlagsInfo::flags includes VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT, the bufferDeviceAddress feature must be enabled (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.211.0/linux/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkMemoryAllocateInfo-flags-03331)"', src/vulkan/hardware_interface.rs:709:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

It seems, from the message I need to enable an extension.

Confusion n1, it seems this should always be enabbled, according to the docs:
https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_buffer_device_address.html

Because it was moved to be a core extension? Bbut maybe I miss understand what core means, so I tried enabling it manually.

I Have a list of extension names that I pass to the device upon creation:

```
const DEVICE_EXTENSIONS : &'static [&str] =
&[
    "VK_KHR_swapchain",
    "VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering",
    "VK_EXT_buffer_device_address",
    "VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state",
    "VK_EXT_conservative_rasterization",
];

    let extensions : Vec<CString> = DEVICE_EXTENSIONS.iter().map(
        |extension_name| CString::new(extension_name.to_string()).unwrap()
    ).collect();

    let raw_extensions : Vec<*const i8> = extensions.iter().map(
        |extension| extension.as_ptr()
    ).collect();

    let mut dynamic_rendering =
        vk::PhysicalDeviceDynamicRenderingFeaturesKHR {
            dynamic_rendering : true as u32,
            ..Default::default()
        };
    type PDDRF = vk::PhysicalDeviceDynamicRenderingFeaturesKHR;
    let indexing_features =
        vk::PhysicalDeviceDescriptorIndexingFeatures
        {
            p_next : (&mut dynamic_rendering) as *mut PDDRF as *mut c_void,
            shader_sampled_image_array_non_uniform_indexing : true as u32,
            ..Default::default()
        };

    // The enabledLayerCount and ppEnabledLayerNames parameters are deprecated,
    // they should always be 0 and nullptr.
    // https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkDeviceCreateInfo.html
    let create_info =
        vk::DeviceCreateInfo {
            p_next : &indexing_features as *const _ as *const c_void,
            queue_create_info_count : 1,
            p_queue_create_infos : &queue_create_info,
            enabled_extension_count : requested_device_extensions.len() as u32,
            pp_enabled_extension_names : raw_extensions.as_ptr(),
            p_enabled_features : &device_features,
            ..Default::default()
        };
```

A little convoluted, I know, but so far the swapchain extension seems to load just fine, so I don't understand why the device address extension is never enabled.

Someone mentioned I should enable the feature alongside the extension:

```rust
let buffer_address =
        vk::PhysicalDeviceBufferAddressFeaturesEXT
        {
            buffer_device_address : vk::TRUE,
            ..Default::default()
        };

    let dynamic_rendering =
        vk::PhysicalDeviceDynamicRenderingFeaturesKHR {
            p_next : (&buffer_address) as *const _ as *mut c_void,
            dynamic_rendering : true as u32,
            ..Default::default()
        };

    type PDDRF = vk::PhysicalDeviceDynamicRenderingFeaturesKHR;
    let indexing_features =
        vk::PhysicalDeviceDescriptorIndexingFeatures
        {
            p_next : (&dynamic_rendering) as *const PDDRF as *mut c_void,
            shader_sampled_image_array_non_uniform_indexing : true as u32,
            ..Default::default()
        };

    // The enabledLayerCount and ppEnabledLayerNames parameters are deprecated,
    // they should always be 0 and nullptr.
    // https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkDeviceCreateInfo.html
    let create_info =
        vk::DeviceCreateInfo
        {
            p_next : &indexing_features as *const _ as *const c_void,
            queue_create_info_count : 1,
            p_queue_create_infos : &queue_create_info,
            enabled_extension_count : requested_device_extensions.len() as u32,
            pp_enabled_extension_names : raw_extensions.as_ptr(),
            p_enabled_features : &device_features,
            ..Default::default()
        };
```

But I still get the same error even with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned on the Khronos Vulkan Discord that you got it working with the piece of code I posted using ash's builder pattern and `push_next` features, but I think I see why your original code triggers the validation layer.

### Enabling the feature

You're enabling `VK_EXT_buffer_device_address` and using its structure `VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeaturesEXT`,
but `VK_EXT_buffer_device_address` was deprecated by `VK_KHR_buffer_device_address`; it was promoted to a KHR extension.

Worth nothing here is, that `VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeaturesKHR` is *not* an alias for `VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeaturesEXT`, it's a different structure (... with identical layout).
They therefore have different `sType` values:

```cpp
// Provided by VK_EXT_buffer_device_address
VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES_EXT = 1000244000,

// Provided by VK_VERSION_1_2
VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES = 1000257000,
// Provided by VK_KHR_buffer_device_address
VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES_KHR = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES,
```

Now let's check the [relevant piece of code](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/blob/49314e06675ac87e2711f0b50d12426f1a2cf85b/layers/parameter_validation_utils.cpp#L6030-L6053) for the validation layer, where it checks for the `VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT` flag for `vkAllocateMemory`:

```cpp
VkBool32 buffer_device_address = false;
// --snip--
const auto *bda_features = LvlFindInChain<VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeatures>(device_createinfo_pnext);
if (bda_features) {
  capture_replay = bda_features->bufferDeviceAddressCaptureReplay;
  buffer_device_address = bda_features->bufferDeviceAddress;
}
```

It tries to find a `VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeatures` in the `pNext` chain, which is an alias for `VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeaturesKHR`, *not* the EXT one, as can be seen from the [source code](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/blob/07851b8a0c299631b1bb717e319ca184cf55bb69/layers/generated/vk_typemap_helper.h#L6406-L6419) for `LvlFindInChain`:

```cpp
// Find an entry of the given type in the const pNext chain
template <typename T> const T *LvlFindInChain(const void *next) {
// --snip--
    if (LvlTypeMap<T>::kSType == current->sType) {
```

```cpp
// Map type VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeatures to id VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES
template <> struct LvlTypeMap<VkPhysicalDeviceBufferDeviceAddressFeatures> {
    static const VkStructureType kSType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES;
};
```

That is, the validation layer looks for a structure with
`sType` == `VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES` == `1000257000`,
*not* one with `VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_FEATURES_EXT` == `1000244000`,
therefore it concludes that `bufferDeviceAddress` feature is not enabled.

You needed to use the promoted KHR one to satisfy the validation layer, even though your Vulkan driver probably supported the deprecated EXT one as well.

### gpu-allocator

As for why using the gpu-allocator crate seemingly necessitated enabling buffer device address,
I'd suggest checking if you accidentally set `gpu_allocator::vulkan::AllocatorCreatorDesc::buffer_device_address` to `true`.
This is what [prompts the library](https://github.com/Traverse-Research/gpu-allocator/blob/b645446a90428f4ee3dbbeb6565dee93252fd210/src/vulkan/mod.rs#L150-L154) to use `VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT` when calling `vkAllocateMemory`:

```rust
let allocation_flags = vk::MemoryAllocateFlags::DEVICE_ADDRESS;
let mut flags_info = vk::MemoryAllocateFlagsInfo::builder().flags(allocation_flags);
// TODO(manon): Test this based on if the device has this feature enabled or not
let alloc_info = if buffer_device_address {
  alloc_info.push_next(&mut flags_info)
```